# Apache 2.4 redirect https to another port

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I'm a rookie, but I've struggled with this for some time and I am definitely doing something wrong.

We use Apache 2.4 as the front of our internal web pages.

When I try to forward a request to a port other than 80, it goes crazy and is redirected several times
http://demos.company.com/demos.company.com/demos.company.com/demos.company.com/demos.company.com/demos.company.com/demos.company.com/[...]/demos.company.com/WebApplicationFail

httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^(.*) %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files/Apache24/conf/ssl/company.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Program Files/Apache24/conf/ssl/company.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Program Files/Apache24/conf/ssl/CA.pem"

    # Proxy configuration
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName demos.company.com

    ProxyPass /WebApplicationOK http://10.0.0.160/WebApplicationOK
    ProxyPassReverse /WebApplicationOK http://10.0.0.160/WebApplicationOK
    ProxyPass /WebApplicationFailRoute http://10.0.0.125:8000/WebApplicationFail
    ProxyPassReverse /WebApplicationFailRoute http://10.0.0.125:8000/WebApplicationFail
</VirtualHost>
```

We need to maintain the redirection of every http request to https.

If possible, we need that the Internet address "https://demos.company.com/ThisContext" show the intranet web "http://10.0.0.125:8000/OtherContext".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your <VirtualHost *:80> you probably want to redirect to `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: Do you have any error while restarting httpd service?

Comment: Is the apache and redirecting server on the same machine?

Comment: No, I don´t have any error when starting the Apache.

The Apache 2.4 machine redirect to webs in other machines (usually with Tomcat or other Java application server)

Answer (score 2):

That's the problem with adding complex directives for trivial tasks.

You have a Virtualhost which uses port 80, why even check for SSL?, everything it will receive will not be SSL.

Also the rewrite directive is missing the scheme.

So just:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

If you don't need to use variables, for variable host names I would go even simpler:

```
Redirect / https://whateverhost.example.com/
```

Rule to success in httpd: Go always with the most simple option.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
The redirection from http to https is already working.
What I want is that when you make a request to the address "https://demos.company.com/WebApplicationFailRoute", the web page "http://10.0.0.125:8000/WebApplicationFail" is displayed, that is not published on the Internet.
The result is too many redirections.
The problem is in the port, when I do a redirection to the standard port, it works.
"https://demos.company.com/WebApplicationOK", shows "http://10.0.0.160/WebApplicationOK" properly.

Comment: sorry I don't follow.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it, it simple actually. You just only add those lines for redirection from below to your ssl.conf I guess

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName XXXX.ddns.net
    # These are your SSL settings; your responsibility
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXX.ddns.net/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXX.ddns.net/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    # Your document root; where the JavaScript application lives
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html/ >
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny 
        Allow From All
    </Directory>

    # Reverse proxy settings for API (custom redirection https to specific port)
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Location /api >
        ProxyPass        http://127.0.0.1:3000/api
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/api
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It works to redirect to a port, thank you @Rizky Yoga Oktora. Would there be some way to redirect the context and the port at the same time?  
  
    _<Location /context1 >
        ProxyPass        http://otherhost:3000/context2
        ProxyPassReverse http://otherhost:3000/context2
    </Location>_

  myhost/context1 redirects to myhost/context2, but it doesn't seem to take the port.